# Objective C: Navigation title is overridden

Tags: objective-c, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have 3 storyBoards, `A`, `B` and `C`.
`A` has a  `TabBarController`.

When I move from `A` to `B` I make it like the code bellow:

```
BViewController* vcB = (BViewController*) [R2Utils getViewControllerWithId:@"BViewController" fromStoryBoard:StoryboardB];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController animated:YES];
```

where vcB is the `NavigationController` in the storyboard `B`.

when navigating from `B` to `C`:

```
UINavigationController* nav = (UINavigationController*)  [R2Utils getViewControllerWithId:@"MainAppNavigationController" fromStoryBoard:StoryboardC];

[UIView transitionFromView:self.window.rootViewController.view
                                toView:nav.view
                              duration:0.8f
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                self.window.rootViewController = nav;
                            }];
```

The problem is that the title of the navigation bar is being overridden by a navigation bar of previous Controller(check the image).
[image]

Comment: You are transitioning from a view to another view. Is that intentional. You'd want to call `transitionFromViewController` on the ViewController. Since the bar is managed by the VC, you get those weird artifacts.

Comment: You can try this way might be it will work. In viewWillAppear you can hide navigation bar of previous Controller.And viewWillDisappear you can unhide of same navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the problem was:
The previous controllers from storyboard `B` are still in the heterarchy. The `navigationController` in storyboard `C` has a `backgoroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`.
So in storyBoard `C`, we can see the `title` of the current controller and the content of the `navigationController` bar in storyBoard `B`